# Aliasing a subdomain on a wordpress network

Tags: multisite, apache

I have a subdomain network install with the primary at http://test.domain.com.  One of the sub-sites exists at http://sub.test.domain.com.  I'd like to be able to access that sub at http://honky.domain.com but I'm stuck on how to make that work.  Ideas?

Also, I'd yet another alias to access that sub, but by a different domain.  In other words, I'd also like to access that sub at http://www.supercooldomain.com.  No idea how to make that happen either.

FWIW, I'm using apache as the web server.

Answer (score 0):

So far as we know, we can control the subdomain by the Wordpress subdomain network and apache rewrite rule(nginx works too.).

The subdomain is a rule, so you can't set it directyly in .htaccess by using your http://www.supercooldomain.com, but you can set another apacahe virutal host use your cooldomain. There is another wordpress plugin may can help you. 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/